HTML collection has elements but indices are null
I have a table and want to color the numbers based on their amount. Therefore, I try to get the innerHTML (with the number) of the td's with class="account-balance" in javascript.
The problem is that the indices of the HTML collection that I get back are null, which they are definitely not and the indices are existing.
function setBalanceColor() {
  console.log(dataTBody.getElementsByClassName("account-balance"));
  console.log(dataTBody.getElementsByClassName("account-balance")[1]);
  console.log(dataTBody.getElementsByClassName("account-balance")[1].innerHTML);
}


And that is what's inside the innerHTML of index [1]:

Using .item(1) instead of [1] leads to the same result. Also different index numbers are the same. I have no clue what the reason could be. Someone who got an idea?

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

HTMLCollections are live; it are automatically updated when the underlying document is changed. Console logs are also not snapshots and update too.

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { document.querySelectorAll('td.account-balance').forEach(td => td.classList.add(returnColorClass(parseInt(td.textContent))));}); - now you just need a function to return a colour depending on the value passed

Thank you very much! That finally worked for me. I had also another mistake through an async function, which is why the content wasn't there to this time.
